# java generic statement in List

Tags: java, generics

Can someone summarize what is the difference between:

```
List<SpecificType>
List<Object>
List
```

Suppose I have:

```
class Car {
    void foo() {}
}

public class Generics_Statement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car c1 = new Car();
        Car c2 = new Car();
        Car c3 = new Car();

        List<Car> carList = List.of(c1,c2,c3);
        System.out.println(carList.get(0).getClass());      // >>> class Car
        System.out.println(carList.get(0) instanceof Car);  // >>> true

        carList.get(0).foo();

        List<Object> objList = List.of(c1,c2,c3);
        System.out.println(objList.get(0).getClass());      // >>> class Car
        System.out.println(objList.get(0) instanceof Car);  // >>> true
        // objList.get(0).foo();


        List rawList = List.of(c1,c2,c3);
        System.out.println(rawList.get(0).getClass());      // >>> class Car
        System.out.println(rawList.get(0) instanceof Car);  // >>> true
        // rawList.get(0).foo();

    }
}
```

I do understand the importance of claiming the right type, one should definitely use `List<Car>` here.

I do understand using raw type should be avoided.

And I understand for a fact that `objList` and `rawList` can't use `Car.foo` because I didn't clearly claim the type in the `List`

What I don't understand is that:

1. It seems that it still recognize the element in `objList` and `rawList`, and return the right class and confirmed that the element is an instance of `Car`. WHY? If it knows the `Class` of the elements, shouldn't it be able to call `Car.foo`?
2. Is `List<Object>` and `List` the same thing?
3. Any other difference that I don't know yet?

Comment: It knows the type at *runtime* and not at *compile time* and hence you cannot call `foo` on it.

Comment: @user7 I am trying to digest what this means. You mean the compiler does not allow this, but JVM allows?

Comment: Would you change being you, when I wouldn't call you "Code_Control_jxie0755", but just "user" (i.e. `List<Object>`) or "someone" (i.e. `List` where I don't even know if you're a user). No, you wouldn't, but I (the compiler) don't know anymore who I am dealing with.

Comment: @Tom  Your metaphor is suggesting that `List<Object>` and `List` are different as one is "user" and the other is just "someone".   But `Object` is already the very basic, why isn't both `List<Object>` and `List` "someone"?

Comment: Haven't you said you know that raw types should be avoided, but you don't know why? Then read this: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2770321). That also answers your question.